# How do I use rewrite on Lighttpd?

Tags: url-rewriting, lighttpd

I'm trying to use rewrite on Lighttpd but I cannot get it to work.

I try the following:

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "asdf.com" {
    server.document-root = "/home/www/asdf.com"
    url.rewrite = ( 
        "/^test/$" => "/test.html",
    )
}
```

but I just receive an 404 error when I visit `asdf.com/test/`
I have also tried without the `$HTTP["host"] {}` option, but that also give me a 404 error.

In the lighttpd.conf I have the following:

```
  server.modules = ( 
     "mod_rewrite",
```

I tried several examples but everything just seems to give me a 404 error. Are there any commands I can use to check if the rewrite module is actually enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the rewrite:

```
"^/test/$" => "/test.html",
```